# Choropleth with fixed polygons and updateable region values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, charts, geojson

I'm trying to make a choropleth map visualization with fixed polygon regions, but variable data for each region that depends on a query. Currently I have the polygon coordinates in KML and SHP format, and I could convert it to GeoJSON if needed.

Basically what I want it to do is to load a map with those regions once, and be able to update the values + fill colors of those regions whenever new data is requested / received through an AJAX callback. The most important is it doesn't unnecessarily reload the region polygons, i.e. I could just supply a JSON object of region id's and their new values).

I already tried using the Google Maps API, but I can't seem to bypass generating an entire new KML file each time I want to load new values. This forces me to unnecessarily reload the region shapes as well, although they never change. I tried caching the KML clientside in a JS object, updating it's values each time new data is received and then re-setting the map (using geoxml3), but this seems to perform rather slow (since the entire KML is being iterated and since it's a pretty large file including all the region coordinates). FusionTables didn't work for me either because I need to fetch the data from my own database, and from what I understand using FusionTables you can only query a FT table.

As far as I know the Gmaps API probably isn't going to work for me. Which other solution could suit my needs best?

Comment: Have you looked at d3.js choropleth? It can be flexible and interactive. https://vida.io/documents/qyRt8bFozMqfaw6Av

Answer (score 0):

Google just added GeoJSON support to the Maps API. This example does something similar to what is described above:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/combining-data